# Removing a control in Visual C++ 2005 (MFC)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, mfc

I have a MFC dialog in Visual C++ 2005, (MFC Application) and I have added several controls to it. But Visual Studio has no option for deleting a control if I no longer need it.
Is there any easy way to do that except modifying all the code where a reference to the control appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to automatically remove all related code. One method that can help the manual removal is to use "Find all references" *before* removing the object in the designer. Then after deleting it, navigate to the references and remove the related code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure selecting the offending control on the design sheet and pressing delete works?

Comment: It does, but doing so leaves behind portions of code in the header and cpp files, and you will get a pretty ugly error 99% of the time. I was thinking about deleting the control and all code associated with it.